# spring tool suite 4 console prints a lot of thread related logs

Tags: spring-boot, spring-tool-suite, spring-boot-devtools

I downloaded Spring tool suite 4 and now i am trying to run my spring boot application. but i ran into this issue of lots of unnecessary logs being printed on my console.

I restarted STS as well as my pc but none of it worked.

[image]

this keeps printing continuously and so i can't even see if i print something from my code.

Comment: so this ends up in the same console view than your regular app output?

Comment: yes it keeps printing on and on.

Comment: can you provide a few steps how to reproduce this, starting from a vanilla STS install?